# First item on the jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using [jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu Plugin](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/options/) I ran into a problem: the first menu item is always open - even if refresh the page. Yes, the state of open tabs menu should be maintained (see settings below), but each time you visit the site the first item is expanded (I repeat: even if roll it and refresh the page). How to solve this problem? I quote the following settings of the plug-in:

```
$('ul.menu').dcAccordion({
        classParent: 'with-submenu',
        eventType: 'click',
        saveState: true,
        disableLink: true,
        speed: 'fast',
        cookie: 'menu'
    });
```

Thanks.